# LINQ query to a custom class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a class which has the following fields:

```
public Account account;
public IEnumerable<PurchaseTransaction> purchases;
```

Basically, I want to select each 'Account', and perform an *outer* join to the purchasetransactions table, and select all the purchases and place them in the 'purchases' IEnumerable (or leave empty if there's no purchases), and the Account in the 'account' field. How easy is this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `GroupBy` will come in handy.  It automatically creates the IEnumerable for you also!

Example:

```
from row in db.purchases
group row by row.AccountID into g
select g;
```

`g` is already an IEnumerable containing all the purchases for the account ID which is stored in `g.Key`.

Comment: Thanks - how would I go about selecting linking to an Account object in the same query and selecting that too?

Comment: In LINQ-to-SQL, you can use `LoadWith`.  However, it is not recommended as it expands the size of data retrieved.  Better to load the accounts first, then load the purchases in a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by joining onto the purchases then selecting them into a new instance of my class.